# How to make Chrome obey this rule?

Tags: html, textbox, google-chrome, width

Here is the code:

```
<table style='margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: right;'>
 <tr>
  <td style='vertical-align: top;'>Title:</td>
  <td style='width: 400px;'><input type='text' style='border: 1px solid black; width: 100%;' />
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style='vertical-align: top;'>Content:</td>
  <td><textarea style='border: 1px solid black; width: 100%;' rows='7'></textarea></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Here is what it looks like in Opera and FireFox (in Linux):

http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/nuisance/opera.png
http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/nuisance/firefox.png

But then in Chrome (also in Linux):

http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/nuisance/chrome.png

As you can see, the first text box is not the right width :(

How can I fix this?

**Update:** [here](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/nuisance/test.html) is a live page that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Works for me. Could you provide a link to live website?

Comment: its just a guess, but youre missing the `cols` attribute on your `textarea`. probably not the problem, but maybe worth a try.

Comment: @Fyo: Sorry for the delay: http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/nuisance/test.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha! Now that you've posted a live link, this is much more clear.

The problem is, your `textarea` has a padding of 2px from left and right. Therefore, it's right edge is calculated as `2px + 100%`, which evaluates to "*2px to the right from the `td`'s right edge*" (because `td`'s right edge is 100%).

(I hope this is clear enough; I'm trying my best :-)

To fix this, either put `padding: 0` on the textarea, or put `padding: 0 2px` on the input.